# different ways how Linux TCP/IP stack terminates connection

Tags: kernel, tcp

I have a Linux machine which connects to SSH server with SSH client(OpenSSH_4.1p1). SSH client machine has IP address 10.10.11.1 and SSH server has IP address 10.10.10.1. SSH client has kernel version 3.2.0-4 and SSH server has kernel version 2.6.38-8. If I SIGTERM the SSH client, the TCP/IP connection is terminated either like this:

```
root@localhost:~# tcpdump -ni eth2 tcp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
17:03:53.313956 IP 10.10.11.1.48340 > 10.10.10.1.22: Flags [F.], seq 699217476, ack 226096330, win 913, options [nop,nop,TS val 236994467 ecr 236953581], length 0
17:03:53.315108 IP 10.10.10.1.22 > 10.10.11.1.48340: Flags [.], ack 1, win 280, options [nop,nop,TS val 236958986 ecr 236994467], length 0
17:03:53.315931 IP 10.10.10.1.22 > 10.10.11.1.48340: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 280, options [nop,nop,TS val 236958986 ecr 236994467], length 0
17:03:53.315950 IP 10.10.11.1.48340 > 10.10.10.1.22: Flags [.], ack 2, win 913, options [nop,nop,TS val 236994468 ecr 236958986], length 0
^C
4 packets captured
4 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
root@localhost:~#
```

..or like this:

```
root@localhost:~# tcpdump -ni eth2 tcp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
17:09:03.135285 IP 10.10.11.1.48341 > 10.10.10.1.22: Flags [F.], seq 2985791777, ack 685840991, win 913, options [nop,nop,TS val 237071923 ecr 237029567], length 0
17:09:03.137040 IP 10.10.10.1.22 > 10.10.11.1.48341: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 280, options [nop,nop,TS val 237036440 ecr 237071923], length 0
17:09:03.137077 IP 10.10.11.1.48341 > 10.10.10.1.22: Flags [.], ack 2, win 913, options [nop,nop,TS val 237071923 ecr 237036440], length 0
^C
3 packets captured
3 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
root@localhost:~#
```

Both of those examples are not ["by the book"](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination-2.htm). In first example both hosts send SYN along with FIN("F." in *tcpdump* output). Why is this so? I would expect those to send only the FIN as shown in the TCP/IP guide. Second example is also confusing- where is the ACK from 10.10.10.1?

Comment: There are no SYN flags in the trace you listed; only FIN and ACK.  It looks like you simply did not capture the opening of the connection and only got the perfectly normal close.

Comment: `SYN` would be an `S` flag in the output. `F` is `FIN`, `.` is `ACK`. The only difference between the two traces is whether the ACK piggy-backed on the server's FIN or gets sent by itself first. That's probably just due to how quickly the server application notices the EOF and exits.